# javax.el.ELException: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: spring, mvc

Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста как решается данное исключение:
javax.el.ELException: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session

вот код jsp:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%--<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"%>--%>

<html>

<style>
    .prokrutka{
        overflow: auto;
    }
</style>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Company list</title>
    <link href="<c:url value='/static/css/bootstrap.css' />" rel="stylesheet"></link>
    <link href="<c:url value='/static/css/app.css' />" rel="stylesheet"></link>
</head>

<body class="prokrutka">
<div class="generic-container">
    <%--<%@include file="authheader.jsp" %>--%>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <!-- Default panel contents -->
        <div class="panel-heading"><span class="lead">List of company </span></div>
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>CompanyName</th>
                <th>Phone number</th>
                <th>City name</th>

            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <c:forEach items="${companies}" var="companies">
                <tr>
                    <td>${companies.companyId}</td>
                    <td>${companies.companyName}</td>
                    <td>${companies.phoneNumber}</td>
                    <td>${companies.getCityName()}</td>

                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

код контроллера:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin/getAllcompany")
public class GetAllCompany {

    @Autowired
    CompanyService companyService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listCompany(ModelMap model) {

        List<Companies> companies = companyService.getAll();
        model.addAttribute("companies", companies);
        return "/admin/getAllcompany";
    }
}
```

код сущности Companies:

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "COMPANIES")
public class Companies {


    @Id
    @Column(name = "COMPANY_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "COMPANIES_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "COMPANIES_SEQ", sequenceName = "COMPANIES_SEQ")
    private long companyId;

    @Column(name = "COMPANY_NAME", nullable = false, length = 30)
    private String companyName;

    @Column(name = "PHONE_NUMBER", length = 30)
    private String phoneNumber;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CITY_ID")
    private Cities city;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "company")
    public List<Buses> buses = new ArrayList<Buses>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "company")
    private List<Drivers> drivers = new ArrayList<Drivers>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "company")
    public List<Routes> routes = new ArrayList<Routes>();

    public Companies() {
    }

    public String getCityName(){
        return city.getCityName();
    }

    public long getCompanyId() {
        return companyId;
    }

    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public Cities getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public List<Buses> getBuses() {
        return buses;
    }

    public List<Drivers> getDrivers() {
        return drivers;
    }

    public List<Routes> getRoutes() {
        return routes;
    }

    public void setCompanyId(long companyId) {
        this.companyId = companyId;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setCity(Cities city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public void setBuses(List<Buses> buses) {
        this.buses = buses;
    }

    public void setDrivers(List<Drivers> drivers) {
        this.drivers = drivers;
    }

    public void setRoutes(List<Routes> routes) {
        this.routes = routes;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Companies companies = (Companies) o;

        if (companyId != companies.companyId) return false;
        if (companyName != null ? !companyName.equals(companies.companyName) : companies.companyName != null)
            return false;
        if (phoneNumber != null ? !phoneNumber.equals(companies.phoneNumber) : companies.phoneNumber != null)
            return false;
        if (city != null ? !city.equals(companies.city) : companies.city != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = (int) (companyId ^ (companyId >>> 32));
        result = 31 * result + (companyName != null ? companyName.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (phoneNumber != null ? phoneNumber.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (city != null ? city.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

код репозитория:

```
   @Repository
public class CompaniesRepository extends AbstractRepository<Companies> {
    public CompaniesRepository() {
        super(Companies.class);
    }

    public Companies findByCompanyName(String companyName) {
        Criteria criteria = createEntityCriteria();
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("companyName", companyName));
        return (Companies) criteria.uniqueResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: Покажите полный текст ошибки и листинг companyService.

Comment: Спасибо, я уже разобрался. Проблема была в том как данные подгружаются, т.е. в зависимости от нотаций  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) и т.д.

Comment: Напишите ответ на свой вопрос. Вдруг кто-нибудь ещё с этим столкнётся.

Comment: Я думаю этой ссылки вполне будет достаточно:http://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/lazy-loading-in-hibernate/